# Facebook Graph API version change - can't retrieve posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

Since Facebook's Graph API changed to version 2.4, I find that any query attempting to retrieve posts made returns an error:

```
    type: OAuthException, code: 1, message: An unknown error has occurred. [HTTP 500]
```

My request code uses Facebook's koala ruby api to make requests:

```
     posts = @graph.get_object(appid+"/posts?limit=20",api_version: "v2.3")
```

I added the version count now, based on koala's recommendation, but the result for this is still the same error that I got without specifying the version. My access token is definitely valid, does anyone know if something else has changed or if this is a bug?

Comment: Waht are you trying to query? An app has no `/posts` edge...

Comment: @Tobi: In v2.3, this always worked for me in the graph api explorer: candycrushsaga/posts, and the result is : http://pastebin.com/rEuMrDCM

Comment: @Tobi: Still works when I'm querying an app for posts ie. /posts is a valid edge in v2.3. For GET /v2.3/candycrushsaga/posts, response is https://gist.github.com/tvishwa107/a4441cb045177e119b0f.

Comment: That's a page name, not an app name

Comment: @Tobi: I don't quite understand the difference, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending @Tobi 's comment. You have to pass a page/event/user/group id to retrieve the post.

Also, you've to explicitly pass `fields` parameter to query additional data of a post. So your query will become:

```
posts = @graph.get_object(id+"/posts?fields=id,name,message,picture&limit=20",api_version: "v2.4")
```

Please refer to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post) document of Facebook Developers to learn more about `/posts`edge.

Comment: is this a change from v2.3 to v2.4? In v2.3 all I had to do was search /candycrushsaga/posts in the Graph API Explorer to retrieve all posts+all their likes, shares, and comments.

Comment: Edit: Using this doesn't change the result, I still get an OAuth code 1 HTTP 500 Error

Comment: Yes, this is a change applicable from API v2.4. Make sure you are passing a valid id representing page/group/event/user and user access_token in case of retrieving of an users post.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what works for you? Graph API Explorer lets me query 2.3 - style and get results, but I can't do the same using koala

Comment: How would I go about retrieving the comments on a particular post?

Comment: Pass post id to the `/comments` edge. Ex. `{post-id}/comments?summary=1&filter=toplevel`